# Web Client SSL certificate authentication in WCF using Transport Secruity

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, ssl, https

We have implemented the WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) service and want to authenticate Client using SSL certificate. For demo we have tested this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650785.aspx) (it is working perfectly). In production environment, we have a Wildcard certificate for our organization as *.abc.com from Rapid SSL.

The WCF service is hosted on the Windows Azure VM and client is an Azure website hosted by someone else. The WCF service is working properly as:

`https://demo.abc.com/testservice/tenantMgmt.svc`

In Example code, we have generated the Client certificate using demo CA.

- Do we need to buy another certificate from the Rapid SSL for Azure Client?

In Azure website, we can't upload certificate to Trusted Root, they are always installed in [Personal folder](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/27/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/). So we need CA to be already public verified.

As service provider, we need to give them certificate for SSL Authentication.

- What the best way to resolve the following issue?

Any other suggestion are also welcome.

Comment: The certificate needs to be installed in trusted root on the server.

Comment: The client **believes** the CA provided it trusts it. If you are able to get your SSL certificate that certifies the authenticity of *.abc.com to the `Trusted Publishers` of the client machines, you are clear. So the real question is, can you get your certificate installed there?

Comment: This seems like a better question for http://security.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/ It's not really to do with programming per se